# action not showing logs in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a action called like so:

```
export const makePayment = (values) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log("current payment is ", values);
  res = await axios.post(domain + "/api/makePayment", values);
  console.log("payment done", res);
};
```

That I'm calling like so from my react native component when a button is pressed using props.makePayment:

```
const Payment = (props) => {
  const [filled, setFilled] = useState(false);
  const [values, setValues] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View>
      <CreditCardInput
        onChange={(form) => {
          form.status.cvc == "valid" &&
          form.status.expiry == "valid" &&
          form.status.number == "valid"
            ? setFilled(true) && setValues(form.values)
            : setFilled(false);
        }}
      />
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          filled
            ? console.log("current investment is ", props.currInvestment) &&
              props.makePayment(values) &&
              Alert.alert("Invested")
            : Alert.alert("Incorrect Payment Method");
          // navigation.navigate('OwnScreen', {artistName:props.artistName,
          // mediaName:props.mediaName, uri:props.uri,description:props.description });
        }}
        style={({ pressed }) => [
          {
            backgroundColor: pressed ? "white" : "#03befc",
          },
          styles.own,
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={styles.ownText}>Pay</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Here are mapStateToProps and connect:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { currInvestment: state.currInvestment };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { makePayment })(Payment);
```

However, I'm not seeing the console.log in the actions after pressing the button. What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Could you add your `import` statement to `makePayment` ?

Comment: import { makePayment } from "../actions";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is combining statements using `&&`:

```
console.log("current investment is ", props.currInvestment) &&
          props.makePayment(values)
```

The return value of `console.log()` is not truthy (it is undefined), therefore your `makePayment()` call is never fired, because of the use of the `&&`. Using this, if the first statement is not truthy then no further statements are executed.

Remove that `console.log()` and `makePayment()` will be fired.

To test this you can run:

```
console.log('One') && console.log('Two')
```

Only the first will be executed.